# php - combining the results of looping

Tags: php, loops, merge

I have a code like this

```
            error_reporting(E_ALL ^ (E_NOTICE | E_WARNING)); 
            function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {
                $ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
                $launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
                return  $launch;
            }
            function my_replace($srch, $replace, $subject, $skip=1){
                $subject = explode($srch, $subject.' ', $skip+1);
                $subject[$skip] = str_replace($srch, $replace, $subject[$skip]);
                while (($tmp = array_pop($subject)) == '');
                $subject[]=$tmp;
                return implode($srch, $subject);
            }
            function replace_element($str,$search,$replace,$num) {
                $num = $num - 1;
                $pieces = explode(',',$str);
                if($pieces[$num] == $search) {
                    $pieces[$num] = $replace;
                }
                return implode(',',$pieces);
            } 
            function returnFormat($template, $subject){
                preg_match_all("/\|/", $template, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
                foreach($matches[0] as $v) $subject = substr_replace($subject, "|", $v[1], 1);
                return $subject;
                }   

                $replace = "|";
                $pattern = "\|";

            $string = "101131110|101113110|"; 
            $data = "1020,0000,2022,1023,1024,1025,1024,1025,0000|1020,0000,2022,1023,1027,1025,1024,1025,0000|";
                $char = '3';
                $string = str_replace('|', '', $string);    $positions = array();
                $pos = -1; $b=0; 
                while (($pos = strpos($string, $char, $pos+1)) !== false) {{
                    $positions[] = $pos+1; }

                $result2 = implode(',', $positions);
                $res = explode(',',$result2); 
                $exp = multiexplode(array(",","|"),$data);
                $eyz= my_replace('|', ',', $data, 0);       
                $z=1; $y=1;
                foreach ($res as $val) {
                    $res2[$z]=$val; 
                    $valz = $res2[$z];
                    $z++; 
                    }
                        foreach ($exp as $value) {
                        $exp2[$y]=$value; 
                        $vals = $exp2[$valz];
                        $y++; 
                        } 

                        $items = explode(',',$eyz); 
                        $occurences = array_count_values($items);   
                        $st=$occurences[$vals];
                        $fix=replace_element($eyz,$vals,'JJJJ',$valz);

                preg_match_all("/$pattern/", $data, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
                    foreach($matches[0] as $v) $fix = substr_replace($fix, $replace, $v[1], 1);
                    echo "<br/>RESULT : <br/><font color='green'>".$fix."</font>";      
                        $b++;
                }
```

I have a result like this

> result 1 :
>   1020,0000,2022,1023,JJJJ,1025,1024,1025,0000|1020,0000,2022,1023,1027,1025,1024,1025,0000|
>   result 2 :
>   1020,0000,2022,1023,1024,1025,1024,1025,0000|1020,0000,2022,1023,1027,JJJJ,1024,1025,0000|

how to combine the result of looping, so has output like this :

> 1020,0000,2022,1023,JJJJ,1025,1024,1025,0000|1020,0000,2022,1023,1027,JJJJ,1024,1025,0000|

thanks in advance

regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all("/$pattern/", $data, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    foreach($matches[0] as $v) $fix = substr_replace($fix, $replace, $v[1], 1);
        $arrayToCombine[] = explode(",", $fix);
    $b++;
}
array_replace( $arrayToCombine[0], $arrayToCombine[1] );
```

But I've to ask: In your example there are 2 *results* with about 16 values separated by commas. And the combination output that you show us also has 17 values separated by commas... Do you want something like removing array duplicates in the combined array?

```
array_unique( array_merge( $arrayToCombine[0], $arrayToCombine[1] ) )
```

**UPDATE:** try this:

```
preg_match_all("/$pattern/", $data, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    foreach($matches[0] as $v) $fix = substr_replace($fix, $replace, $v[1], 1);
        $arrayToCombine[] = multiexplode([","], $fix);
    $b++;
}
function combine_arrays( $array1, $array2 )
{
    $size = max( count($array1), count($array2) );
    $data = array();
    // I see now, there is the final: add precedence to the 'JJJJ'
    for ($i=0; $i < $size; $i++) { 
        $thisVal = ( $array1[$i] == 'JJJJ' OR $array2[$i] == 'JJJJ' ) ? 'JJJJ' : $array1[$i];
        $data[] = $thisVal;
    }       

    return $data;
}
print_r(combine_arrays( $arrayToCombine[0], $arrayToCombine[1] ));
echo(implode(",",combine_arrays( $arrayToCombine[0], $arrayToCombine[1] )));
```

Comment: i do not want to remove anything, in the case above, i want JJJJ merge in the same position

Comment: i have tried your syntax but not display the output as above, can you tell me again, thanks in advance

Comment: Now check if there is a JJJJ and make the merge... Also removed the | from the explode.

Comment: seems almost perfect, but there were inserted 1020,0000,2022,1023,JJJJ,**1024**,1025,1024,1025,0000|1020,0000,2022,1023,1027,**10‌​25**,JJJJ,1024,1025,0000|

Comment: okay axel, i'll be waiting for updates, thank you very much for your time and help

Comment: i've tried it, yes perfectly, the problem has been resolved, you really helped me. thank you.

Comment: thank you axel, but now i have a new problem if $data is more than one, then the result is : can not redeclare combine_arrays (), how to fix it, e.g:   `$s=mysql_query("select * from tab");
while ($j=mysql_fetch_array($s)) {  $string=$j[1]; $data=$j[2]; .........................syntax/code............................... function combine_arrays( $array1, $array2 )
{ ... } echo(implode(",",combine_arrays( $arrayToCombine[0], $arrayToCombine[1] )));  }`

Comment: Do you copy the combine_arrays function? And what do you mean with _if a $data is more than one_? =)

Comment: the combine_arrays function he was in while if the data is more than one, oOps I mean, $data more than one :D =) yes, if $data more than one, I got an error : can not redeclare combine_arrays ()

Comment: i mean if $data and $string retrieved from a database that contains a lot of data, I got an error : can not redeclare combine_arrays (), because I put in a while loop

Comment: Ohhh... Move the function to the top of the file. Don't put it in the while. Because in every iteration it will redeclare it.

Comment: I have tried to put/move on, and absolutely no error, but the results echo: the second data, and others, to be the same as the first

Comment: e.g. another example data at database: `$string: 101111310|101111310| and $data : 1020,0000,2022,1023,1024,1025,0000,1025,0000|1020,0000,2022,1023,1024,1025,0000,‌​1025,0000|` but thanks to the previous code, I will try it. if there is a new idea I really thank you

Comment: I see, well I remove the | from the multiexplode(). Try to add it

Comment: can you tell me about the latest answers, I have not been familiar with adding, The following are two examples of the output of the data 
`1020,0000,2022,1023,JJJJ,1025,1024,1025,0000|1020,0000,2022,1023,1027,JJJJ,1024,1025,0000|
and
1020,0000,2022,1023,JJJJ,1025,1024,1025,0000|1020,0000,2022,1023,1027,JJJJ,1024,1025,0000|`

the correct result should be a

`1020,0000,2022,1023,JJJJ,1025,1024,1025,0000|1020,0000,2022,1023,1027,JJJJ,1024,1025,0000|
and
1020,0000,2022,1023,1024,1025,JJJJ,1025,0000|1020,0000,2022,1023,1024,1025,JJJJ,‌​‌​1025,0000|`

Comment: maybe I'll show you again that I get the new issue, see the script above, the $string and $data derived from the database, I have a table with the name 'tab', I have A field (I call string) and field B (I call data), first 
`A : 101131110|101113110| B : 1020,0000,2022,1023,1024,1025,1024,1025,0000|1020,0000,2022,1023,1027,1025,1024,1025,0000|`

second
`A : 101111310|101111310| B : 1020,0000,2022,1023,1024,1025,0000,1025,0000|1020,0000,2022,1023,1024,1025,0000,‌​‌​1025,0000|`

Comment: The first successful results using arrays combine function, if $data and $string retrieved from a database that contains a lot of data, I got an error : can not redeclare combine_arrays (), because I put in a while loop, and i move function to the top, and absolutely no error, but the results echo: the second data, and others, to be the same as the first like the example above

Comment: I was away from my computer for a couple of days. Sorry couldn't help you better.

Comment: it's okay axel, thank you for giving inspiration to the above. :)